# how to stop upgrade during ubuntu 22.04 liverserver ISO installation

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates

Issue: Downloaded ubuntu liveserver 22.04 ISO from official site, where it comes by 5.15.0-43 kernel as of (9th December 2022). During install their is a mandatory field "mirror address", by default it comes with http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, here 'us' is the region, we can use http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu as mirror list. As of today (9th December 2022), the updated version iin mirror is 56 version (5.15.0-56), so during install last step its upgrading to 5.15.0-56 kernel.

Solution Required: During and after install we need to get only 5.15.0-43 kernel, it should not update/upgrade to 5.15.0-56 kernel. How to stop update/upgrade during ubuntu liverserver 22.04 installation.

Answer (score 2):

Buried [deep in the installer (*subiquity*)](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/a80a0bd1819faedb0f3644a244482f33fa2af17e/subiquity/server/controllers/kernel.py#L48) is the logic that the name of the kernel package that gets installed is contained in the file `/run/kernel-meta-package`.  Typically, [this file contains](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/hooks/03-kernel-metapkg.chroot_early?id=90067f99e22ff4302c641048e2a708f0e74359a1#n11) `linux-generic`.  The easiest way to change the contents of this file is probably using cloud-init to configure the installer environment.

Here is a basic cloud-init file that will result in an installed system with the kernel package `linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic`.

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - |
    cat <<EOF > /run/kernel-meta-package
    linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic
    EOF
```

The installer will need to be provided the cloud-init file.  As stated in the thread [Cloud-init and the live server installer](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/cloud-init-and-the-live-server-installer/14597)

> The easiest meta-data source to provide is “NoCloud” which is documented at https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html

This solution could also be adapted to [install 5.15.0-25](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443600/need-to-install-ubuntu-22-04-live-server-with-specific-kernel-verison-5-15-0-25), or any other available kernel package.

**notes**

- I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).
- This is probably a bad idea because an old kernel package that possibly contains security issues will be installed.

**update**

Newer versions of *subiquity* have had a [kernel autoinstall option](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/0dd4ee7bae15e768ddacfa37ef11e27c721d7c04/documentation/autoinstall-reference.md#kernel) added.  And a [bug fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1989353) that prevents the `/run/kernel-meta-package` file from taking precedence over this autoinstall option.

With these newer versions of *subiquity* the autoinstall configuration to install kernel `linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic` would be

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  kernel:
    package: linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic
```