# How to stop updates during online cloudconfig autoinstall

Tags: 22.04, cloud-init, autoinstall

I am trying to deploy a VM using packer and cloud-config autoinstall.
I am using ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso image which comes with linux kernel 5.15.0-25

During the configuration, kernel version remains the same but after a reboot the kernel version used to get updated to 5.15.0-89(till few weeks earlier) and now to 5.15.0-91.
The problem is I am not able to control this behavior of kernel getting updated to some version.

Due to this I have to recompile my applications.
I am aiming to have a fixed version
Here is the reference to my user-data file for auto install

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
    version: 1
    early-commands:
        # workaround to stop ssh for packer as it thinks it timed out
        - sudo systemctl stop ssh
    packages: [open-vm-tools, openssh-server, curl, wget] 
    network:
        network:
            version: 2
            ethernets:
                ens160:
                    dhcp4: true
    identity:
        hostname: ubuntu-appliance
        username: ubuntu
        password: "$6$rounds=4096$ntlX/dlo6b$HXaLN4RcLIGaEDdQdR2VTYi9pslSeXWL131MqaakqE285Nv0kW9KRontQYivCbycZerUMcjVsuLl2V8bbdadI1"
    ssh:
        install-server: true
        allow-pw: true
        authorized-keys:
            - ssh-rsa   <key>      
    user-data:
        disable_root: false
    late-commands:
        # TBD - this sudoers setup effectively makes the ubuntu user a root user.  Need to tighten that up
        - echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
        - curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
```

So far after reading through the forums & taking reference I tried adding things in
for eg

```
    #cloud-config
    package_update: false
    package_upgrade: false
    apt:
        curthooks:
          mode: builtin
        geoip: false
        preserve_sources_list: false
        disable_suites: [updates, backports, security, proposed, release, universe, multiverse]
```

in late commands

```
    - curtin in-target --target=/target apt-mark hold linux-image-generic
    - curtin in-target --target=/target apt-get update
    - curtin in-target --target=/target apt-get install -y linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic
```

but so far nothing seems to be working.
I tried to run this also "dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades" but same results.
Kernel gets updated to the latest version.

After reading & taking references I could not achieve it, can someone point out where I am going wrong or what exactly I need to change so that the kernel does not update to latest version or it just update to the version I specified.

[yaml template & kernel version in file on vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDJwC.png)

Comment: Do you just want to install a specific kernel?  Check out https://askubuntu.com/q/1444758/376778

Comment: Hi @AndrewLowther thanks for the reply.
I tried to follow the steps mentioned in link but its still loading with the default kernel which comes with the ISO and then updates to the latest security release after the reboot.
I checked the file /run/kernel-meta-package it doesn't reflects with the value i entered in template.
I updated the question with the image of yaml and content of the file

Comment: Look closer at the example in the link.  The `runcmd` key is at the top level of the yaml and **not** nested under the `autoinstall` key.  This is because `runcmd` is part of the *cloud-init* configuration.

Comment: yup I missed that, thanks for pointing it out.
and the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
apt:
    fallback: offline-install
```

for my air-gapped images. Maybe it could help?